# Change Jupyter notebook config directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How to change jupyter config location other than /home/username directory?

I can use following to create config in normal circumstances. But for a special purpose, /home directory of the account I'm using doesn't exist and I cannot create one.

`--generate-config
    generate default config file`

Comment: This http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#since-jupyter-does-not-have-profiles-how-do-i-customize-it may be what you need.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR)

On linux, you can change the default config folder by setting the environment variable: `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR`. (*Set it in your `~/.profile` for bash users or `~/.zprofile` for zsh users to have it persist across sessions*).

Next, run

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

to generate the default notebook config in the new config folder